# First historical register of an improper fraction

Tags: mathematics, notation

I'm looking for the earliest known written register of an improper fraction, that is, a numerical fraction in which the numerator is greater than the denominator (like 3/2). By the way, who invented the term "improper fraction" for such fractions? I've tried to look at the traditional references (Cajori's book of mathematical notation) for these informations, but no luck.

Comment: If it's not in Cajori, then I doubt anyone would know, as this does not strike me as something that would have been investigated by math historians, who probably now investigate things like this much less than in Cajori's time. I recommend trying some simple google-books searches for "vulgar fraction", with earlier and earlier date specifications. For example, [here is a google-books search for "vulgar fraction" restricted to the 19th century](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vulgar+fraction%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899).

Comment: The method suggested by @DaveLRenfro brings up instances from 1771 for "improper vulgar fraction" and 1677 for "improper fraction"; I wonder what other European language equivalents are.

Comment: See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/8467/origin-and-use-of-the-adjective-improper-in-mathematics/8469#  In particular the portion of my answer on "proper fraction" and "improper fraction".

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I think that's a good enough link to close this question